# SQL where 'does not contain Numerics', is it possible?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table full of rows, each row has a status and a sequence id (and a bunch of super secret stuff which isn't important here). The status is either a string indicating the current status of the record, or an id number indicating it is a child to a parent with that sequence number, who will contain the status of the tree. Basically our table contains Trees where the parents hold status information and all the children contain upward pointers. (It's pretty bad designed I know, but it is legacy and not worth changing quite yet.)

First what I need is a list of all of the statuses for all of our families, and their sequence ids. So I would need something like

```
SELECT UNIQUE status, seq_id FROM top_secret_database.government_secrets_table 
WHERE status <does not contain numerics>
```

does anyone know a way to accomplish this in sql?

I can do

```
SELECT UNIQUE status, seq_id FROM top_secret_database.government_secrets_table 
WHERE status NOT IN (
    SELECT UNIQUE seq_id FROM top_secret_database.government_secrets_table
)
```

But at this point I'm just curious if there is any way to get any regex like 'not numerics' in sql that anyone knows of because that would be useful done the line. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help if you tell us what database is this

Comment: Its Teradata, which tends to be quite limiting...

Comment: REGEX will be available in Teradata 14. There are UDF's available to download that provide you IsNumeric() functionality from the Teradata Developer Exchange, if you are permitted to add UDF's to your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the acceptable range of numeric status ids you could use the Teradata native `CHAR2HEXINT()` function to determine if the first character of the column is a character or numeric.

```
SELECT CHAR2HEXINT('A')
     , CHAR2HEXINT('Z')
     , CHAR2HEXINT('0')
     , CHAR2HEXINT('1')
     , CHAR2HEXINT('9')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say WHICH sql server you're using, so I'm going to assume [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT ...
WHERE status NOT REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the status is either a string containing no numbers, or a fully numeric Id, you can use (at least in TSQL) the [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function to filter.